# Beginner to C: Getting frustrated on a simple program

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a, b;
    scanf("%c", &a);
    scanf("%c", &b);

    printf("%c %c",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, I only get output as a & I don't get the prompt to enter 2nd character. Why?

Comment: Please use more relevant/detailed titles for questions. This is not a website for psychological help. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this line,

```
scanf("%c", &a);
```

you are actually taking a %d from the stdin (standard input) but at the time you entered a character from stdin, you also typed ENTER from your keyboard which means that now you have two characters in stdin; the character itself & \n. So, the program took first character as `the one you entered` & second character as `\n`.

You need to use

```
scanf("%c\n", &a);
```

so that scanf *eats* the newline (that came by pressing ENTER) too.

As [rodrigo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/865874/rodrigo) suggested, you can use these too.

```
scanf(" %c", &a); or scanf("%c ", &a);
```

The way you are thinking that second character is printed is wrong. It's actually being printed but it's \n so your prompt might be coming to the next line.

Your code will work if you enter both characters without using ENTER.

```
shadyabhi@archlinux /tmp $ ./a.out 
qw
q wshadyabhi@archlinux /tmp $
```

Note, when you used this, the only thing in STDIN was q & w. So, the first scanf ate `q` & the second one `w`.

Comment: So, does that mean I should always use "\n" while using scanf()?

Comment: Well, not so. In this case it will work, but your code will work fine if you type both `char`s in a single line. In that case you wouldn't need to bother about `\n`.

Comment: @FlopCoder No, using a space will cause second character to be space. It won't work.

Comment: I prefer to use `scanf(" %c", &a);` or `scanf("%c ", &a);`. The blank character in the format string eats up all the blank characters (including ENTERs) present in the input stream.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you press the `enter` key, the resulting newline is read as a separate character into `b`. Try this instead:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a, b;
    scanf("%c %c", &a, &b);

    printf("%c %c",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The %c is a format string which accepts only a single character. I think you pressed Enter key as soon as you pressed an alphabet key. The Enter key is also recognized as a character. So the next variable is taking the enter key which has a value of "\0".
The computer is still printing the character from the second variable but its invisible since nothing is getting printed. If you keenly observe, there will be a new line.
Enter two characters one after the other and you will be getting the right output.